# Apache2 won't load css files on Debian 6 (Squeeze)

Tags: apache-http-server, debian-squeeze

After using nginx for a few months, which worked pretty well, I decided to switch back to Apache.
Now, I have just installed apache2, but it seems like it won't load my CSS files. I've been struggling with it for hours now and I don't know what else to do; I just did a clean install from Apache and created this virtual host (see below) but it still doesn't work.

E.g.: http://shurl.be/

This is the virtualhost I'm using for it (note that I have commented out the rewrite rules):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@wouterds.be
     ServerName shurl.be
     ServerAlias www.shurl.be
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/www.shurl.be/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/www.shurl.be/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/www.shurl.be/logs/access.log combined

     #     RewriteEngine On
     #     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     #     RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?a1=$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_mime and add the following lines in your httpd.conf (or a .htaccess):

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```

Comment: Thanks, works now. Very weird, it should just work out of the box. I should't add this manually.

And no, I haven't changed ANYTHING to the configuration files.
That's what makes it so weird it didn't just work by itself.

Comment: @Simon I am having same issues, however followed this answer and still cannot load .css files

Comment: What do you mean by 'not loading'?

Is it not adding the text/css Content-Type header or is the file not sent to the browseR?

Answer (score 0):

When I load your website and look into the console, it displays the following error

> [16:37:08.652] The stylesheet http://shurl.be/layout/stylesheets/css/test.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css". @ http://shurl.be/

It seems you're missing an appropriate mime type. Although, the default configuration of debian should do this already.

Comment: Exactly it should just work.. Anyway, how can I add it manually?