# How to enable mod_mime on apache2

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, mime-types

I am running apache2 on debian 6. I am wondering how do I enable mod_mime? according to [an Answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/553475/apache2-wont-load-css-files-on-debian-6-squeeze), I need mod_mime loaded so that my webserver can load .css files. Current Modules I have loaded Are:

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -M
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

when I try `sudo a2enmod mod_mime` I get `ERROR: Module mode_mime does not exist!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead

```
sudo a2enmod mime
```

The `mod_` prefix is implicitly added.

`a2enmod` will look for `/etc/apache2/mods-available/MODULENAME.load` where `MODULENAME` is the name you supplied as an argument.

The file would then be symlinked to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/MODULENAME.load`.

If you look at the contents of that file, it should say:

```
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
```

This tells us that the `mod_mime.so` library will later be loaded as `mime_module`.

Comment: hmmm, says it is already enabled. mod_mime obviously must be the same as mime_module

Comment: @Richard: You're correct. I added additional information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know how I setup apache to load .css files. I added lines `AddType text/css .css` and 
`AddType text/javascript .js` to `apache.conf`, however style sheets are still not loading.

Comment: @Richard: I don't really understand the linked question. Apache shouldn't really care about the type of the file. The settings regarding `mod_mime` affect what Apache will tell the *client* what type the file is. Please feel free to post an additional question outlining your original problem. Maybe we can find a solution :)