# The stylesheet css/style.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css"

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, css

I tried the solution proposed in this thread: [Apache2 won't load css files on Debian 6 (Squeeze)](https://superuser.com/questions/553475/apache2-wont-load-css-files-on-debian-6-squeeze)

I added `.htaccess` files in every directory, containing

```
AddType text/css .css   
AddType text/javascript .js
```

But it did not work.

Neigther worked the Apache howto http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#page-header, telling me to place the types in the `Directory` directive in `apache2.conf`

The `mime_module (shared)` is loaded.

Anything I found via Google led me to one of those two solutions.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mime types for CSS and javascript should be enabled per default. Check if the mime module is loaded, by running:

```
apachectl -M | grep mime
```

It should return "mime_module (shared)". If not, enable the mime module by running

```
sudo a2enmod mime
```

If the mime module is enabled, but those types are not defined, you can add them to the file
/etc/mime.types (for the whole system) or /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf (for apache). 
If you want to use .htaccess file, you have to enable them first (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles), but I would recommend to make sure that these types are enabled centrally.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same issue. I had imported the bootstrap file in my application.css at the top. It was causing me issues.

So I placed the same import at the bottom after the comment lines in the application.css file. It worked like a charm!

Comment: Unbelievably, this was actually the issue for me as well...